# SQL Select with broken table relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, inner-join, relationship

I have a table structure on Postgree like this:

```
Table1
    pktab1
    somedate
    valor
Table2
    pktab2
    fktab1
    valor
Table3
    pktab3
    fktab1
    fktab4
    valor
Table4
    pktab4
    condition
```

They´re related through PK & FK keys of each table.

The field *table1.value* controls whether I have values on table2 or table3.

table1.value = 1 | table2.value = NULL / table3.valeu = XX

table1.value = 2 | table2.value = XX / table3.valeu = NULL

I need a resulting table with 3 columns: table1.date, table2.value and table3.value

I´m trying to do a select using the following syntax:

```
select 
    table1.somedate,
    table2.valor,
    table3.valor
from table1
   inner join table2 on (table2.fktab1 = table1.pktab1)
   inner join table3 on (table1.pktab1 = table3.fktab1)
   inner join table4 on (table3.fktab4 = table4.pktab4)
where 
      (table1.valor = 2 and table4.condition = 1)
       or 
      (table1.valor = 1)
```

But it only returns NULL values.
I also tried using:

```
where   
    (table1.value = 1 and table4.condition = 1)
    or
    (table1.value = 2 and table4.condition IS NULL)
```

But also didn´t work.

If I remove Table2 from the query, everthing works fine.
It seems to me that in some records the where clause "table4.condition = XX" is unreacheable, causing the whole query to be NULL, but I just don´t know how to make a turn around this.

Anyway to solve it?

Comment: Try using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOIN` for `table2`.  Sounds like you don't have corresponding data in that table.

Comment: Impossible to say for sure without knowing your schema but @sgeddes is likely to be right. All that filters and joins cannot find a match meaning there something wrong in your logic

Comment: @sgeddes Thanks! It worked! In my case, I had to left join all tables then It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

As @sgeddes suggested, I used `LEFT JOIN` then the problem was solved.